# Opscenter 4.1.4: Authentication failing

Tags: cassandra, agent, opscenter

I'm getting authentication errors when starting the opscenter agents on each of my cassandra (v1.2.5) nodes:

```
INFO [main] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,880 Starting Stomp
INFO [main] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,881 SSL communication is disabled
INFO [main] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,881 Creating stomp connection to <ipaddr>:61620
INFO [Initialization] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,885 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,909 Reconnecting in 0s.
INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,919 Connected to <ipaddr>:61620
INFO [main] 2014-07-23 12:18:03,976 Starting Jetty server: {:port 61621, :host nil, :
     ssl? false, :join? false}
WARN [Initialization] 2014-07-23 12:18:04,112 Error when trying to match our local  
     token: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
INFO [Initialization] 2014-07-23 12:18:04,117 Sleeping for 2s before trying to 
     determine > IP over JMX again
```

I've manually installed these agents from tarballs. I've not yet found clear documentation on how the Opscenter agent, server & cassandra node initialise with one another it's not clear to me what is wrong. Can someone point me to what configuration I need in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to specify credentials for Cassandra via the Edit Cluster form in the OpsCenter UI.  These will automatically be sent to the agent which will use them to connect to the local node.

Comment: Correct; assuming you are already running a SSH-server on the node. Be also sure you installed the sysstat packages as this is needed to get it fully working.